# Reference for integral equation result

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, lp-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $T>0$, $X := L^2([0, T])$ and $\Gamma: X \rightarrow X$ be defined as
$$
(\Gamma u)(t) := \int^t_0 k(t, s)u(s)~\mathrm{d}s,
$$
where $k \in L^2([0, T]^2)$.

I am rather certain that $\mathrm{Id} - \Gamma$ is invertible (I know that it is if $k \in L^\infty([0, T]^2)$). Does anyone have a literature reference for this result?

Comment: This is a kind of Volterra operator, which is known to be a Hilbert--Schmidt operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) with your assumption on $k$. If $\|k\|_{L^2}  = c < 1$, then the spectrum of $\Gamma$ is contained in $\overline{B}(0,c)$, so $I - \Gamma$ is invertible. I don't know what about the case $c\geq 1$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_alternative#Integral_equations

Comment: Is it a Hilbert Schmidt-Operator though? Note the dependency on $t$ in the integral boundary...

Comment: Yes, I have forgotten about that. You have to replace the kernel $k$ with $\widetilde{k}(s,t) = k(s,t) \cdot \chi_{(0,t)}(s) \leq k(s,t)$.